# WinXP with too many windows open, file explorer window is corrupted

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

Here's something that has bothered me for awhile and I wondered if anyone had any ideas.  This has been on multiple computers, but always at work and always on a dual monitor setup running Windows XP Professional.  It's been multiple machines now that have done it, but both machines have had ample RAM and speed.

I'll be running with a lot of applications/windows open.  For example, right now I have 20 items in my taskbar.  Often I'll have multiple Outlook emails opened and multiple Windows Explorer (windows key + E) windows open, too.  I have noticed a problem where at some point, after some amount of items being open(ed) and/or over a period of time, if I hit win+e to open a new explorer window it my system will start feeling unstable and slow, and the new explorer window that opens is graphically corrupted.  Instead of the file/edit/view bar and the navigation bar, it will instead just have a blank gray bar with the Windows logo in the center (which is usually in the upper-right corner).  Closing this new explorer and opening a new one won't fix it - usually it's only if I close out extra open windows to trim down how many things are open that I'm able to recover and open a new explorer window and have it work normal.

Is there a limit to the number of native explorer windows you can open in XP, or the number of windows/applications in general?  Outlook and explorer.exe seem to be the worst offenders, closing out extra of those windows.

Comment: edmicman, it seems like one of your programs eats a lot (most) of so called GDI counters. Use the Nir Sofer's GDIView utility to locate that program, and avoid using it.

Answer (score 1):

From here: http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2007/02/07/max-num-of-open-windows-under-xp-2003-vista-resolved.aspx (read the full article)

> To tweak the limit, take a look in the
>   registry at
>   **HLKM/System/CurrentControlSet/Control/Session
>   Manager/SubSystems**
>
> (cranked up a bit if you find yourself
>   manipulating a lot of desktop
>   objects.)
>
> Within that key is a subkey called
>   **Windows**, which contains in it, among
>   other things, the value
>   "**SharedSection=1024,3072**"
>
> Changing the SharedSection entry to
>   "**1024,3072,512**" (note the comma and
>   the value)increases the size of the
>   "hidden" desktop heap.
>
> If that doesn't work, try increasing
>   the second of the comma delimited
>   values (e.g. 3072 -> 4096) which is
>   the size limit of any particular
>   desktop heap.
>
> **Update: just to clarify for some
>   pepole... on vista your default is
>   1024,3072,512 changing is to
>   1024,4096,512 will make the difference**

Answer (score 0):

**One Feature That Will Help Gaurenteed**

The other possibility is explorer having too many files open at once. A good fix for this is to enable "Launch folder Windows in a separate Process". It's a little know feature of windows that allows the machine to separate file/folder access from the Explorer GUI process (been around since XP).

It can be found under Control Panel > File Explorer Options > "View" Tab > Launch folder Windows in a separate Process

**Possibility #1**

If the folder is deleted or moved explorer windows will close themselves. Are these folders being manipulated in anyway?

**Possibility #2**

Alternatively, you can check to make sure that explorer hasn't become corrupted. 1. Launch an administrator commandline (Win + X) -> Press "A"
2. Click yes to accept the UAC prompt
3. Type this command "sfc /scannow" (without the quotes)

Windows will scan all of its core files and fix any problem it finds. I am an IT professional and explorer generally starts to behave after theses steps have been exhausted.